# Tranpose Rows to Columns while keeping part of dataframe in tact

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to move some of my rows and make the them columns, but keep a large portion of the dataframe the same.

My Dataframe looks something like this:

```
ID  Thing      Level1 Level2  Time OAttribute IsTrue Score Value
1   bicycle    value  value  9:30  whatever    yes   1     type1
2   non-cycle  value  value  1:30  whatever    no    2     type2
3   bicycle    value  value  2:30  whatever    yes               
4   bicycle    value  value  3:30  whatever    no    4     type3
```

And I want something like this:

```
ID  Thing Level1 Level2  Time OAttribute      IsTrue  Type1  Type2 Type 3
1   bicycle    value  value  9:30  whatever     yes   1     
2   non-cycle  value  value  1:30  whatever     no            2
3   bicycle    value  value  2:30  whatever      yes               
4   bicycle    value  value  3:30  whatever     no                   4
```

Comment: 5   bicycle    value  value  3:30  whatever     no          2                               on row five. Where 2 is under Type 1 column

Comment: `Score`  is in the results headers but doesn't look like it has a column. Is that correct?

Comment: Yeah that was correct. I'll fix it so it doesnt confuse others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Option 1***
Use `merge`

```
df_ = df[['ID', 'Value']].dropna().set_index('Value', append=True).ID.unstack()

df.drop('Value', 1).merge(df_, right_index=True, left_index=True, how='left').fillna('')
```

[image]

***Option 2***
Use `pd.concat`

```
df_ = df[['ID', 'Value']].dropna().set_index('Value', append=True).ID.unstack()

pd.concat([df, df_], axis=1).drop('Value', 1).fillna('')
```

Comment: Great solution. Fast and simple. Thanks!

Comment: if the ID was the same do you know how I would display two numbers in the same row?

Comment: You'd have to update your question or ask a new one.  Preferably with sample data and expected results that demonstrate what you are asking for.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
In [112]: df
Out[112]: 
   ID      Thing Level1 Level2  Time OAttribute IsTrue  Score  Value
0   1    bicycle  value  value  9:30   whatever    yes      1  type1
1   2  non-cycle  value  value  1:30   whatever     no      2  type2
2   3    bicycle  value  value  2:30   whatever    yes    NaN    NaN
3   4    bicycle  value  value  3:30   whatever     no      4  type3

In [113]: dg = pd.DataFrame(columns=df['Value'].dropna().unique())

In [114]: for i in range(len(df)):
     ...:     key = df.loc[i]['Value']
     ...:     value = df.loc[i]['Score']
     ...:     if key is not pd.np.nan:
     ...:         dg.loc[i, key] = value
     ...:                                                 

In [115]: dg
Out[115]: 
Value type1 type2 type3
0         1   NaN   NaN
1       NaN     2   NaN
3       NaN   NaN     4

In [116]: df.join(dg).drop('Value', 1).fillna('')
Out[116]: 
   ID      Thing Level1 Level2  Time OAttribute IsTrue Score type1 type2 type3
0   1    bicycle  value  value  9:30   whatever    yes     1     1            
1   2  non-cycle  value  value  1:30   whatever     no     2           2      
2   3    bicycle  value  value  2:30   whatever    yes                        
3   4    bicycle  value  value  3:30   whatever     no     4                 4
```

Comment: Thats actually reallly close to what I want, but when I ran it it repeated the columns type1, type2, type3 various times. So I ended up with 20+ columns

Comment: @Kalimantan I have made a small change. While creating the intermediate data frame, you can use `.unique()`

Comment: I chose the other as the answer due to the simplicity, but this works as well. thanks

Comment: if there were repeated ID's do you know how I would display two numbers in the same row?

Comment: I posted a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39421384/row-to-columns-while-keeping-part-of-dataframe-display-on-same-row