# row to columns while keeping part of dataframe, display on same row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to move some of my rows and make the them columns, but keep a large portion of the dataframe the same.

Resulting Dataframe:

```
ID  Thing      Level1 Level2  Time OAttribute IsTrue Score Value
1   bicycle    value  value  9:30  whatever    yes   1     type1
1   bicycle    value  value  9:30  whatever    yes   2     type2
2   bicycle    value  value  2:30  whatever    no               
4   non-bic    value  value  3:30  whatever    no    4     type3
1   bicycle    value  value  9:30  whatever    yes   3     type3
```

and I want something like this:

```
ID  Thing  Level1 Level2  Time    OAttribute   IsTrue  Type1  Type2 Type3
1   bicycle    value  value  9:30  whatever     yes      1      2     3
2   bicycle    value  value  2:30  whatever     yes               
4   non-bic    value  value  3:30  whatever     no                    4
```

I have tried

```
df_ = df[['Rating', 'Value']].dropna().set_index('Value', append=True).Rating.unstack()

df.drop('Value', 1).merge(df_, right_index=True, left_index=True, how='left').fillna('')
```

Comment: I am curious. Type2 with score 2 was associated with the Thing: non-cycle, but in your resulting dataframe, it is associated with Thing: bicycle. Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: If there are multiple IDs with the same value, how do you decide which value of IsTrue will come in the resulting dataframe? Similar query goes for other attributes like Level1, Level2, Time, OAttribute and Thing.

Comment: When ID is same, are the rows guaranteed to have the same value for the attributes (Thing, Level1, Level2, Time, OAttribute, IsTrue)?

Comment: Ok I edited so the only difference is in the Score and value columns. I think that makes more sense and still achieves what I want

Comment: ID = 4 is non-bic in previous and bicycle in the new one. How does that happen?

Comment: I hadn't caught that. Sometimes aligning in stack overflow is hard due to the formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to create an intermediate dataframe and then use outer merge.

```
In [102]: df
Out[102]: 
   ID    Thing Level1 Level2  Time OAttribute IsTrue  Score  Value
0   1  bicycle  value  value  9:30   whatever    yes    1.0  type1
1   1  bicycle  value  value  9:30   whatever    yes    2.0  type2
2   2  bicycle  value  value  2:30   whatever     no    NaN    NaN
3   4  non-bic  value  value  3:30   whatever     no    4.0  type3
4   1  bicycle  value  value  9:30   whatever    yes    3.0  type3

In [103]: dg = pd.DataFrame(columns=pd.np.append(df['Value'].dropna().unique(), ['ID']))

In [104]: for i in range(len(df)):
     ...:     key = df.loc[i]['Value']
     ...:     value = df.loc[i]['Score']
     ...:     ID = df.loc[i]['ID']
     ...:     if key is not pd.np.nan:
     ...:         dg.loc[i, key] = value
     ...:         dg.loc[i, 'ID'] = ID
     ...:                 

In [105]: dg
Out[105]: 
  type1 type2 type3 ID
0     1   NaN   NaN  1
1   NaN     2   NaN  1
3   NaN   NaN     4  4
4   NaN   NaN     3  1

In [106]: dg.groupby('ID').max().reset_index()

In [107]: dg
Out[107]: 
   ID  type1  type2  type3
0   1      1      2      3
1   4    NaN    NaN      4

In [108]: df[df.columns.difference(['Score', 'Value'])].drop_duplicates().merge(dg, how='outer').fillna('')
Out[108]: 
   ID IsTrue Level1 Level2 OAttribute    Thing  Time type1 type2 type3
0   1    yes  value  value   whatever  bicycle  9:30     1     2     3
1   2     no  value  value   whatever  bicycle  2:30                  
2   4     no  value  value   whatever  non-bic  3:30                 4
```

Another way to calculate the intermediate data frame would be by avoiding the for loop and using [unstack()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
In [150]: df
Out[150]: 
   ID    Thing Level1 Level2  Time OAttribute IsTrue  Score  Value
0   1  bicycle  value  value  9:30   whatever    yes    1.0  type1
1   1  bicycle  value  value  9:30   whatever    yes    2.0  type2
2   2  bicycle  value  value  2:30   whatever     no    NaN    NaN
3   4  non-bic  value  value  3:30   whatever     no    4.0  type3
4   1  bicycle  value  value  9:30   whatever    yes    3.0  type3

In [151]: dg = df[['Score', 'Value']].dropna().set_index('Value', append=True).Score.unstack().join(df['ID']).groupby('ID').max().reset_index()

In [152]: df[df.columns.difference(['Score', 'Value'])].drop_duplicates().merge(dg, how='outer').fillna('')
Out[152]: 
   ID IsTrue Level1 Level2 OAttribute    Thing  Time type1 type2 type3
0   1    yes  value  value   whatever  bicycle  9:30     1     2     3
1   2     no  value  value   whatever  bicycle  2:30                  
2   4     no  value  value   whatever  non-bic  3:30                 4
```

Comment: I don't want it to give me the sum but if I take it out it gives me a cannot merge with type GroupBy

Comment: @Kalimantan The sum() is actually being used here only so that for example: 1+NaN+NaN returns 1. Nothing else. I am not calculating any other sum()

Comment: in some columns I get 16, additionally one of my columns values are being omitted

Comment: From what I understand the sum function would add all 1's that have the same ID, whereas I would want the value to still be 1

Comment: @Kalimantan You can replace `.sum()` with `.max()` . I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can't really tell what you're trying to do with both of your Score and Value columns at the same time.

But if you're looking to transform your "Value" column, you're looking for something like one-hot encoding of your "Value" column and pandas has a very convenient function for it. All you have to do is:

```
pd.get_dummies(df['Value'])
```

That will give you a new data frame with 3 new columns namely [type1,type2,type3] filled a bunch of 1s and 0s.

After that, all you have to do is use the .join command to join it back to your original df. You can then proceed to delete the columns that you don't need.

Comment: sorry I had a typo that made it confusing